# AWS provider credentials not found when getting SSM param on serverless

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner, aws-serverless, aws-ssm

I'm attempting to get a SSM param for the params in my serverless.yml

Without it, `sls deploy` works as expected, it's adding that param that breaks the deploy. The credentials are set up on a gitlab runner user the export command for access key id and the secret access key.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
before_script:
    - pip install virtualenv
    - python -m virtualenv venv_api
    - source venv_api/bin/activate
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
    - apt-get install -y nodejs
    - npm config set prefix /usr/local
    - npm install -g serverless
    - serverless plugin install -n serverless-dynamodb-autoscaling
    - serverless plugin install -n serverless-python-requirements
script:
    # deploy to staging env
    - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    - sls deploy --stage staging --verbose
```

**serverless.yml**

```
params:
    default:
        SOME_VARIABLE: ${ssm:SOME_VARIABLE}
[...]
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.9
  region: us-west-2
[...]
```

The error I'm getting is

```
$ sls deploy --stage staging --verbose
Running "serverless" from node_modules
Environment: linux, node 18.12.1, framework 3.25.0 (local) 3.25.0v (global), plugin 
6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
Error:
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
  - Cannot resolve variable at "params.default.SOME_VARIABLE": AWS 
    provider credentials not found. Learn how to set up AWS provider credentials in 
    our docs here: <http://slss.io/aws-creds-setup>.,
```

Comment: How are you defining your stage based variables in SSM (e.g. are you using any specific, stage based path?) There is some issue with non null values for stage based variables, with a workaround mentioned here - https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/10671#issuecomment-1064294563